# InsertionSort mistake

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I need help to understand my mistake. I'm trying to make the insertion sort but it doesn't work.

```
void insertionSort(int A[]) {
    int temp, j, d;

    for (int i = 1; i <= dim - 1; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (d > 0 && A[d-1] > A[d]) {
            temp = A[j];
            A[j] = A[j - 1];
            A[j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of 'd' variable?

Comment: More importantly, what is the *value* of the `d` variable?

Comment: I use it to check if the first number is greater than the second one

Comment: @Nickol _d_ is not set, its value is undefined

Comment: @bruno I just set it, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is not initialised, so it would have garbage value.
and i think you have to try following

```
for (int i = 1; i <dim; i++) {
    j = i - 1;
    d = A[i];
    while(j>=0 && A[j-1] > d){ 

       /* other code */
       j = j-1;

    }
    A[j+1] = d;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problem as following:

1. `d` should be replaced by `j`
2. The function prototype should be `void insertionSort(int A[], int dim)`
3. The logic for insertion is not correct.

so here is my modification based on your source code:

```
void insertionSort(int A[], int dim)
{
    int temp, j;
    for (int i = 1; i < dim; i++) {
        temp = A[i];
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && A[j - 1] > temp) {
            A[j] = A[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        A[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Is there another way easier to make is ?

Comment: It’s insertion sort. So you need to do with this style only